# Centering Buttons in Material Design Card (Vue)

Tags: vue.js, material-design, vue-component

I am trying to center buttons within a Material Design Card.

Most of what I've tried has been related to the `<md-card-actions>` tag.
What I've tried that hasn't worked:

```
<md-card-actions md-alignment="center"> 
<md-card-actions md-alignment="center-center">
```

Code Below.

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <!-- Line 4 here, with the link rel pulls google icons and roboto icons, this is part of Vue Material -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,400italic|Material+Icons"> 
    <md-card md-elevation-15>
      <md-card-actions md-alignment="center"> 
        <md-button>Action</md-button>
        <md-button>AnotherAction</md-button>
      </md-card-actions>
    </md-card>
  </div>  
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .md-card {
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: center;
  }
</style>
```

The actual results of this can be seen here:

[image: https://imgur.com/zPLOIbi]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda old, but I ran into the same issue. This is how I solved it:

Add some CSS to your component:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .center-span {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
</style>
```

Then pop a span around your buttons within the md-card-actions element and apply that CSS class to the span:

```
<md-card-actions>
        <span class="center-span">
            <md-button class="md-dense md-mini md-icon-button md-transparent" @click="firstPage">
                <md-tooltip md-direction="top">First Page</md-tooltip>
                <md-icon>first_page</md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <md-button class="md-dense md-mini md-icon-button md-transparent" @click="previousPage">
                <md-tooltip md-direction="top">Previous Page</md-tooltip>
                <md-icon>navigate_before</md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <md-button class="md-dense md-mini md-icon-button md-transparent" @click="nextPage">
                <md-tooltip md-direction="top">Next Page</md-tooltip>
                <md-icon>navigate_next</md-icon>
            </md-button>
            <md-button class="md-dense md-mini md-icon-button md-transparent" @click="lastPage">
                <md-tooltip md-direction="top">Last Page</md-tooltip>
                <md-icon>last_page</md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </span>
</md-card-actions>
```

This is the result:

[image]